# Extending the enumerations

Tags: c++, enums, factory

I have a design problem.

I have a polymorphic structure with an interface A (abstract one) and a workflow implemented in class W which uses the interface A without knowing the derived classes. This is implemented in DLL1 and I have a factory interface F capable of returning A*.
In DLL2, I have the concrete implementations of A, which could be A1, A2 etc. and a factory implementation F1 capable of creating A1 and A2 instances.

The factory interface which I have is something like this.

```
enum ObjectType{typeA1, typeA2};

class F
{
    public:
    A* create(enum ObjectType) = 0;
}
```

Some client class which knows both DLL1 and DLL2 will give me the concrete object type.

But this is ugly since I will have to know the possible types of the concrete classes upfront when I write my DLL1. And this almost defeats my purpose of the polymorphic design. I don't want to do this.

The alternative option which I can think of is to use strings, instead of the enumeration. But, I like to avoid strings as they are not type-safe and are prone to errors. I wish I had a chance to extend the enums by inheritance, just like the classes.

My questions :

Is there a better way out?
Is extension of enums possible in C++11? (I don't have it now, though)

Comment: An alternative to an enum or string is a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid).

Comment: In C++ enums cannot be inherited. In most languages that allow this, inheritance works in an opposite direction from what most people think. It does not *extend* enums, it *contracts* them. Strange but true, and there are very good reasons for that. So your idea could not possibly work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your abstraction to allow the user of interface `A` to also provide the particular factory that creates it. (instead of providing an `enum`).

```
// In DLL1
class AbstractF {
public:
    virtual A * create () = 0;
};

template <typename ConcreteA>
class ConcreteF : public AbstractF {
public:
    A * create () { return new ConcreteA; }
};
```

Now, each `ConcreteF<>` would need to be passed into code to DLL1 for those parts of the framework that need to create the right concrete instance of `A`. Thus, the framework user must inform the framework which of `A1` or `A2` to create not by passing in an `ObjectType`, but by passing in the correct `ConcreteF` (namely `ConcreteF<A1>` or `ConcreteF<A2>`).

Comment: Note: this is a Dependency Injection.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Thanks, I wasn't aware there was a name for this.

Comment: Yeah, this looks better... I didn't think about the possibility of templates... thanks...

Answer (score 0):

What about letting DDL2 have a "string-to-int" interface that you use to translate a string once, then use that id as the argument to the actual factory? If DLL2 doesn't recognize the string then the creation process can fail right there.